# JOIN over multiple tables with subselect for the newest result is not working

Tags: sql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

TLDR: Get the newest row from the other tables with all the entries in the main table.
But I found no solution yet...

Either what I tried, does not really solve it.
My Last solution, did worked until the timestamps differ what can happen, so it does not list all of them.

Basically we have a main table:

```
Servers: ID, userID, Name, updated (timestamp)
```

And resources tables:

```
 cpu: ID, serverID, Load, updated (timestamp)

memory: ID, serverID,Usage, updated (timestamp)
```

My current version of it, not fully working sadly.

```
SELECT servers.name,servers.ID,servers.updated,cpu.Load,memory.Usage
FROM servers 

LEFT JOIN cpu ON cpu.serverID = servers.ID
LEFT JOIN memory ON memory.serverID = servers.ID 

AND cpu.updated = (SELECT cpu.updated FROM cpu ORDER BY cpu.updated DESC LIMIT 1) 

AND memory.updated = (SELECT memory.updated FROM memory ORDER BY memory.updated DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Does work until the timestamps differ also provides multiple results but I could easy fix that by GROUP BY servers.ID.

Without the subselects, I only the the oldest result, but my goal is to get the newest one.

My expected output would be:

```
Name, ID, Updated, Load, Usage
Server , 1, 00030303, 2.5, 40
Server2, 2, 03365345, 12.5, 80
```

Anyone of you got an idea? If you still need more information please ask.
Thanks

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: @jarlh 10.3.17-MariaDB

Comment: could you please provide ur expected output in table format

Comment: @fa06 I updated the post, please have a look.

Comment: You're using a MariaDB version that supports [window functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions-overview/). You can do what you need with [ROW_NUMBER()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/row_number/).

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use subquery/group by to find the last record for cpu/memory and join with the servers table:

```
SELECT s.name,s.ID,s.updated,c.Load,m.Usage
FROM servers s
LEFT JOIN (SELECT serverID,MAX(updated) AS lastUpdated FROM cpu GROUP BY serverID) cl
ON s.ID=cl.serverID
LEFT JOIN cpu c
ON cl.serverID=c.serverID
AND cl.lastUpdated=c.updated
LEFT JOIN (SELECT serverID,MAX(updated) AS lastUpdated FROM memory GROUP BY serverID) ml
ON ml.serverID=s.ID
LEFT JOIN memory m
ON m.serverID=ml.serverID
AND m.updated=ml.lastUpdated
```